# boost thread list

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, boost

I have code similar to below. The code below gives SIGSEGV and points to list::push_back. Is this the right way to use list of boost threads?

```
struct mythread{
   static void myfunc() {
      while(1){ }
   }
};

int f(){
   std::list<boost::thread *> pool;
   pool.push_back(new boost::thread(mythread::myfunc));
}
```

Environment: gcc 4.4.5 on Ubuntu, linked with libboost_thread.a and -lpthread. I am not using c++0x flag.

Regards,

Chubsdad

Note 2: I also get SIGSEGV for the code

```
pool.push_back(new boost::thread(NULL);
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: list::push_back calls list::_M_Insert which calls _List_node_base::hook. SIGSEGV is from the hook member function

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the address of the function pointer:

```
pool.push_back(new boost::thread(&mythread::myfunc));
```

Comment: Nope. Does not help. I get the crash again.

Comment: Well crap.  I just tried compiling your code on my machine (g++ 4.4.1, ubuntu 9.10) with this modification and it worked without segfaulting.  I honestly can't say that I know what is going on.